# Big integer addition code

Tags: c, math, cuda, biginteger

I am trying to immplement big integer addition in CUDA using the following code

```
__global__ void add(unsigned *A, unsigned *B, unsigned *C/*output*/, int radix){

    int id = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x; 
    A[id ] = A[id] + B[id]; 

    C[id ] =  A[id]/radix;
    __syncthreads();
    A[id] =  A[id]%radix + ((id>0)?C[id -1]:0);
    __syncthreads();
    C[id] = A[id];
}
```

but it does not work properly and also i don't now how to handle the extra carry bit. Thanks

Comment: Have you got it working in a "normal" sequential CPU code?

Comment: Is this similar to what you are trying : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12957116/large-integer-addition-with-cuda ?

Comment: @Cimbali Yes, it is similar, i already saw that question but im trying to achieve it's somehow different here

Comment: @user3246941 Yeah now I've taken the time to go in-depth on the question, it really is a duplicate, except you use `radix` instead of `2^32` or `2^64`, the maximum int the representation can hold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR** build a carry-lookahead adder where each individual additionner adds modulo radix, instead of modulo 2

### Additions need incoming carries

The problem in your model is that you have a rippling carry. See [Rippling carry adders](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adder_(electronics)#Ripple-carry_adder).

If you were in an FPGA that wouldn't be a problem because they have dedicated logic to do that fast ([carry chains, they're cool](http://www.fpga4fun.com/Counters4.html)). But alas, you're on a GPU !

That is, for a given `id`, you only know the input carry (thus whether you are going to sum `A[id]+B[id]` or  `A[id]+B[id]+1`) when all the sums with smaller `id` values have been computed. As a matter of fact, initially, you only know the first carry.

```
    A[3]+B[3] + ?     A[2]+B[2] + ?     A[1]+B[1] + ?     A[0]+B[0] + 0       
        |                 |                 |                 |
        v                 v                 v                 v
       C[3]              C[2]              C[1]              C[0]
```

### Characterize the carry output

And each sum also has a carry output, which isn't on the drawing. So you have to think of the addition in this larger scheme as a function with 3 inputs and 2 outputs : `(C, c_out) = add(A, B, c_in)`

In order to not wait O(n) for the sum to complete (where n is the number of items your sum is cut into), you can precompute all the possible results at each `id`. That isn't such a huge load of work, since `A` and `B` don't change, only the carries. So you have 2 possible outputs : `(c_out0, C) = add(A, B, 0)` and  `(c_out1, C') = add(A, B, 1)`.

Now with all these results, we need to basically implement a [carry lookahead unit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lookahead_carry_unit).

For that, we need to figure out to functions of each sum's carry output `P` and `G` :

- `P` a.k.a. all of the following definitions

  - Propagate
  - "if a carry comes in, then a carry will go out of this sum"
  - `c_out1 && !c_out0`
  - `A + B == radix-1`
- `G` a.k.a. all of the following definitions

  - Generate
  - "whatever carry comes in, a carry will go out of this sum"
  - `c_out1 && c_out0`
  - `c_out0`
  - `A + B >= radix`

So in other terms, `c_out = G or (P and c_in)`. So now we have a start of an algorithm that can tell us easily for each id the carry output as a function of its carry input directly :

1. At each `id`, compute `C[id] = A[id]+B[id]+0`
2. Get `G[id] = C[id] > radix -1`
3. Get `P[id] = C[id] == radix-1`

### Logarithmic tree

Now we can finish in O(log(n)), even though treeish things are nasty on GPUs, but still shorter than waiting. Indeed, from 2 additions next to each other, we can get a group `G` and a group `P` :

For `id` and `id+1` :

4. `step = 2`
5. `if id % step == 0, do steps 6 through 10, otherwise, do nothing`
6. `group_P = P[id] and P[id+step/2]`
7. `group_G = (P[id+step/2] and G[id]) or G[id+step/2]`
8. `c_in[id+step/2] = G[id] or (P[id] and c_in[id])`
9. `step = step * 2`
10. `if step < n, go to 5`

At the end (after repeating steps 5-10 for every level of your tree with less `id`s every time), everything will be expressed in terms of `P`s and `G`s which you computed, and `c_in[0]` which is `0`. On the wikipedia page there are formulas for the grouping by 4 instead of 2, which will get you an answer in O(log_4(n)) instead of O(log_2(n)).

Hence the end of the algorithm :

8. At each `id`, get `c_in[id]`
9. return `(C[id]+c_in[id]) % radix`

### Take advantage of hardware

What we really did in this last part, was mimic the circuitry of a carry-lookahead adder with logic. However, we already have additionners in the hardware that do similar things (by definition).

Let us replace our definitions of `P` and `G` based on radix by those based on `2` like the logic inside our hardware, mimicking a sum of 2 bits `a` and `b` at each stage : if `P = a ^ b` (xor), and `G = a & b` (logical and). In other words, `a = P or G` and `b = G`. So if we create a `intP` integer and a `intG` integer, where each bit is respectively the `P` and `G` we computed from each `id`s sum (limiting us to 64 sums), then the addition `(intP | intG) + intG` has the exact same carry propagation as our elaborate logical scheme.

The reduction to form these integers will still be a logarithmic operation I guess, but that was to be expected.

The interesting part, is that each bit of the sum is function of its carry input. Indeed, every bit of the sum is eventually function of 3 bits `a+b+c_in % 2`.

- If at that bit `P == 1`, then `a + b == 1`, thus `a+b+c_in % 2 == !c_in`
- Otherwise, `a+b` is either `0` or `2`, and `a+b+c_in % 2 == c_in`

Thus we can trivially form the integer (or rather bit-array) `int_cin = ((P|G)+G) ^ P` with `^` being `xor`.

Thus we have an alternate ending to our algorithm, replacing steps 4 and later :

4. at each `id`, shift `P` and `G` by `id` : `P = P << id` and `G = G << id`
5. do an OR-reduction to get `intG` and `intP` which are the `OR` of all the `P` and `G` for `id` 0..63
6. Compute (once) `int_cin = ((P|G)+G) ^ P`
7. at each `id`, get `c_in  = int_cin & (1 << id) ? 1 : 0;
8. return `(C[id]+c_in) % radix`

---

PS : Also, watch out for integer overflow in your arrays, if `radix` is big. If it isn't then the whole thing doesn't really make sense I guess...

PPS : in the alternate ending, if you have more than 64 items, characterize them by their `P` and `G` as if `radix` was `2^64`, and re-run the same steps at a higher level (reduction, get `c_in`) and then get back to the lower level apply `7` with `P+G+carry in from higher level`