# Cuda signed 128-bit multiplication error

Tags: cuda, ptx

I think I discovered a problem when doing 128-bit signed multiplication in cuda PTX using signed integers.
Here is my sample code:

```
long long result_lo, result_hi;
asm(" mul.lo.s64 %0, 0, -1;     \n\t" // 0 * -1 = 0
    " mul.hi.s64 %1, 0, -1;     \n\t"
    : "=l"(result_lo), "=l"(result_hi));
```

This should produce the result `result_lo = 0x0, result_hi = 0x0`. However this produces the result: `result_lo = 0x0, result_hi = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF` which is actualy the value `2^127 - (2^126 - 1)` if I'm not mistaken and clearly not zero.

First off, I want to make sure my understanding is correct, but moreso, is there a way around this?

**Update** Changing from `Debug` mod to `Release` mode fixes this issue, still wondering if this is a bug in cuda?

**Update 2**
Reported this bug to NVIDIA

Used Cuda toolkit 7.5 with Visual Studio 2013. `x64 Debug`, `sm_52`, `compute_52`.

Comment: It may be a bug in debug mode on `sm_52`.  I can reproduce it on `sm_52` debug mode but not on `sm_35` or `sm_20`.  Note that maxwell devices don't have native 64 bit integer multiply operations; the compiler produces sequences of 32-bit ops.  Therefore [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6162140/128-bit-integer-on-cuda) may be of interest.

Comment: @RobertCrovella Since sm_5x (as opposed to sm_2x, sm_3x) does not even have a 32-bit integer multiplier in hardware, the emulation sequences for 64-bit integer multiplication on sm_5x will necessarily differ from the emulation sequences used for sm_2x, sm_3x. A bug report specific to sm_5x seems in order.

Comment: Yes, I've filed a bug already.

Comment: As for a workaround, you would want to make sure that the PTXAS optimization level is at least `-O1`. At PTXAS optimization level `-O0` (which is used for debug builds), a bad emulation sequence is being emitted for `sm_5x` targets (FWIW, this emulation sequence does not look like anything I would expect). So try building with `-Xptxas -O1` or higher.

Comment: @njuffa: That would be a perfect answer, if you care to add it.

Comment: A fix can be observed in [the 361.28 driver](http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/98373/en-us).  It's an issue with the conversion from PTX->SASS as @njuffa has already indicated in his answer.  Therefore, simply loading the 361.28 driver and compiling as usual `nvcc -G -arch=sm_52 ...` will not produce any change in behavior.  However the JIT mechanism in 361.28 contains the fix, so if you compile e.g. without a specific arch flag: `nvcc -G ...` the driver JIT will allow the fix will be observed.  Future drivers and the next major CUDA toolkit release should also pick up the fix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR** This appears to be a bug in the emulation of the PTX instruction `mul.hi.s64` that is specific to `sm_5x` platforms, so filing a bug report with NVIDIA is the recommended course of action.

Generally, NVIDIA GPUs are 32-bit architectures, so all 64-bit integer instructions require emulation sequences. In the particular case of 64-bit integer multiplies, for `sm_2x` and `sm_3x` platforms, these are constructed from the machine code instruction `IMAD.U32`, which is a 32-bit integer multiply-add instruction.

For the Maxwell architecture (that is, `sm_5x`), a high-throughput, but lower-width, integer multiply-add instruction `XMAD` was introduced, although a low-throughput legacy 32-bit integer multipy `IMUL` was apparently retained. Inspection of disassembled machine code generated for `sm_5x` by the CUDA 7.5 toolchain with `cuobjdump --dumpsass` shows that for `ptxas` optimization level `-O0` (which is used for debug builds), the 64-bit multiplies are emulated with the `IMUL` instruction, while for optimization level `-O1` and higher `XMAD` is used. I cannot think of a reason why two fundamentally different emulation sequences are employed.

As it turns out, the `IMUL`-based emulation for `mul.hi.s64` for `sm_5x` is broken while the `XMAD`-based emulation works fine. Therefore, one possible workaround is to utilize an optimization level of at least `-O1` for `ptxas`, by specifying `-Xptxas -O1` on the `nvcc` command line. Note that release builds use `-Xptxas -O3` by default, so no corrective action is necessary for release builds.

From code analysis, the emulation for `mul.hi.s64` is implemented as a wrapper around the emulation for `mul.hi.u64`, and this latter emulation seems to work fine on all platforms including `sm_5x`. Thus another possible workaround is to use our own wrapper around `mul.hi.u64`. Coding with inline PTX is unnecessary in this case, since `mul.hi.s64` and `mul.hi.u64` are accessible via the device intrinsics `__mul64hi()` and `__umul64hi()`. As can be seen from the code below, the adjustments to convert a result from unsigned to signed multiplication are fairly trivial.

```c
    long long int m1, m2, result;
#if 0 // broken on sm_5x at optimization level -O0
    asm(" mul.hi.s64 %0, %1, %2;     \n\t"
        : "=l"(result)
        : "l"(m1), "l"(m2));
#else
    result = __umul64hi (m1, m2);
    if (m1 < 0LL) result -= m2;
    if (m2 < 0LL) result -= m1;
#endif
```