# Assigning 128 bits value to variable in CUDA

Tags: c, vector, cuda

I am trying to implement an encryption cipher in CUDA. It uses 128-bit Key as input. Also, the operations that would be performed on this would be shift operation and addition. I have currently implemented it using array of size 2, each holding 64 bits of data.

From the CUDA documentation, I am able to allocate the vector using

```
int4 make_int4(int x, int y);
```

But unable to perform operations on it. Kindly point me where to look or help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "operations?". Do you mean mathematical operators or math library functions? Also, an int2 is a 64 bit long type, not 128 bit.

Comment: Did you read this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6162140/128-bit-integer-on-cuda

Comment: @Taro Thanks. That was useful. I didn't came across that one.

Comment: @talonmies I meant mathematical operations. And, yeah I did a mistake it was int4 instead of int2. Sorry.

Comment: @ShripalGandhi You're welcome. Glad it was helpful.