# Correct way to sum 128bit numbers represented by 4 32bit unsigned integers?

Tags: c++, cuda, 128-bit

I'm creating a kernel in C++ / CUDA in which I need to sum two 128bit numbers represented as follows:

```
struct Int128 {
    unsigned int bit0_31;
    unsigned int bit32_63;
    unsigned int bit64_95;
    unsigned int bit96_127;
};

Int128 sum(Int128 a, Int128 b) {
    ...?
}
```

What is the most efficient C++ way to achieve this? Thanks.

P.S. Overflow to 129bit can be ignored.

Comment: Which is the wider integral type allowed?

Comment: Possibly relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6162140/580083.

Comment: Since CUDA 11.5, it's possible to use __int128 in device code with compatible host compilers

Comment: I'd like to stick to 32bit math if possible.

Comment: Use `unsigned long long` as the accumulator.  If you can't use that, add them in 16-bit chunks.

Comment: @Eljay can... you give me an example using the ULL as the accumulator?

Comment: `uint64_t acc = a.bit0_31; acc += b.bit0_31; result.bit0_31 = static_cast<uint32_t>(acc); acc >>= 32; acc += a.bit32_63;` and so forth.

Comment: If you need to do a lot of bit twiddling code, I highly recommend Hacker's Delight (2nd ed) by Henry S. Warren Jr.  It's a wonderful cookbook of bit twiddling routines, collected and collated over many years.